# Как загрузить файлы локализации в контекст вне classpathа?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Проект на spring boot
Есть файлы с локазицацией: 
-messages_en_US.properties
-messages_ru_RU.properties
Хочу добавить их в загрузку контекста.
Добавил свой бин настройки MessageSource. Проблема в том, что не могу их читать из какого-нибудь другого места на диске, кроме проекта

> @Configuration public class MessagesConfig { @Bean public
>   MessageSource messageSource() { ResourceBundleMessageSource
>   messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
>   messageSource.setBasenames( "file:/Users/sample/messages" );
>   messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); return messageSource; } }

Ошибка такая

> [GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler.java] [] [handleHttpException] No
>   message found under code 'sampe' for locale 'null'.
>   org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found
>   under code 'sample' for locale 'null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что чтение файла не осуществлялось. Потому, что путь считается относительным.
В доке спринга при загрузке ресурсов сказано, чтобы использовать абсолютный путь надо использовать префикс "file". В resource bundle (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) при этом файл читается как относительный текущей jar.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте абсолютный путь к файлу. 
В разных IDE при нажатии (к примеру в Intellij) `ctrl+space`, вы сможете увидить в какой папке находитесь. 
По дефолту в джаве файлы должны лежать в `/src` или `/resources`, но вы можете подниматься на уровни выше:

`../../src` - здесь вы уже поднялись выше папки `/src` на два уровня.

Comment: Видимо имелось ввиду относительный. Пробовал. Даже если бы помогло, это было бы не удобно так задавать путь. В моем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря для чего вы будет использовать свой код. 
Если в личных целях, на своем компе, то можно создать property файл в котором указывать ссылку к файлу.

Если вы хотите использовать на чужих компьютерах и с минимумом проблем, то можно использовать стандартные папки:

`"user.dir"` - рабочая директория

`"user.home"` - домашняя папка пользователя

Получить их можно командой

```
System.getProperty("имя переменной");
```

Последний вариант, это создавать свою собственную переменную окружения на каждом рабочем компьютере и использовать